# c# wpf Адаптация размера шрифта текста под количеству букв в тексте

Tags: c#, wpf

Как можно адатировать шрифт текста под количеству букв в тексте? 
Никак не могу решить задачу.

[image: п]

Comment: Используйте `Viewbox`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучшая практика - средствами XAML. Просто поместите текст во `ViewBox` и задайте `TextWrapping` равным `Wrap`:

```
<Grid>
 <Viewbox>
     <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Some Text" />
 </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

Или, как вариант, можно сделать при помощи кода на C#:

```
private void SizeLabelFont(Label lbl)
{
    // Вычисляем только при тексте с ненулевой длиной
    string txt = lbl.Text;
    if (txt.Length > 0)
    {
        int best_size = 100;

        // Смотрим, сколько места есть, оставляя
        // зазор для внутреннего отступа лейбла
        int wid = lbl.DisplayRectangle.Width - 3;
        int hgt = lbl.DisplayRectangle.Height - 3;

        // Нужен объект Graphics, чтоб измерить 
        // ширину текста
        using (Graphics gr = lbl.CreateGraphics())
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                using (Font test_font =
                    new Font(lbl.Font.FontFamily, i))
                {
                    // Смотрим, влезает ли текст в отведенные
                    // рамки
                    SizeF text_size = gr.MeasureString(txt, test_font);
                    if ((text_size.Width > wid) ||
                        (text_size.Height > hgt))
                    {
                        // Если нет, то берем предыдущий 
                        // (максимально подходящий) вариант
                        best_size = i - 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // И применяем его
        lbl.Font = new Font(lbl.Font.FontFamily, best_size);
    }
}
```